# acceptable to put select in legend

Tags: html, css

is it acceptable html grammar to put a `select` menu inside of a `legend`?

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <select id="leg_sel">
           <option>asdf</option>    
           <option>asdf</option>  
           <option>asdf</option>  
        </select>     
    </legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
</fieldset>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/xFpkp/

Comment: Why don't you validate it and see?

Comment: [Ask the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the grammar allows it. [From the HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-LEGEND):

```
<!ELEMENT LEGEND - - (%inline;)*       -- fieldset legend -->
```

This means that any inline content is allowed, and inline content includes form fields.

Whether it is useful or semantically correct is a different issue. The `legend` element is defined to be a caption for the enclosing `fieldset`.

Comment: Not so much the grammar as the doctype definition, but other than that...

Comment: thank you. I see what you mean about the semantics. Since this will be a page that won't be available to search engines, is it okay to be semantically incorrect? Are there other reasons beside SEO to remain semantically vigilant?

Comment: @thomas, the impact of semantics is a broad question. I would mostly worry about the confusion effect caused by the rendering. As a user, I would be surprised at seeing a dropdown displayed in a manner that is (somewhat) common for fieldset captions.